# How get only filenames with JSch?

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to create a list of zipped files and their file sizes from a directory on a server. File size is easy to get with the .getSize() method.

However to get only the name of the file. When using the ls command it returns every detail about the zipped files in a directory:

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Sep  6 16:18 test.zip

I have tried to solve this by parsing out the filenames from the returned string, but this seems excessive.

```
        Vector filelist = channel.ls("*.zip");

        for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
            String str = filelist.get(i).toString();
            String fileName = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
            long fileSize =  channel.lstat(fileName).getSize();
            fileName = fileName + ":" + fileSize;
            binaries.add(fileName);

        }
```

What is the correct way to list only the filenames with JSch?

Comment: The elements of the `Vector` returned by `ChannelSftp.ls(String)` are the nested class `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` (although not declared so using Java 'generic' format because Jsch predates java5). Cast to that type and you can then use `.getFilename()` -- and also `.getAttrs()` which already _has_ the info `.lstat(String)` uses another roundtrip to fetch, including `.getSize()` . Alternatively use the `.ls(String,LsEntrySelector)` overload and your own subclass to get the separate name and attrs into your code.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I tried to cast to that type but it says they're not compatiable types:

`ChannelSftp.LsEntry Filename = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) filelist;`

**Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.util.Vector' to 'com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry'**

Comment: Ah sorry I misread that, I'll cast to generic not simple type case.

Comment: See for example [List complete hierarchy of a directories at SFTP server using JSch in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49652526/850848).